# Minimizer of transform function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, optimization

Consider a real-valued function $V(u): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\exists$ $b:=argmin_u V(u)$.

Consider the function $V(\tilde{u})$ with $\tilde{u}=a+\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}$, $a,u \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can I say something about the relation between $b$ and $argmin_u V(a+\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}})$? Is it true that $argmin_u V(a+\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}})=\sqrt{n}(b-a)$? Why? Is it necessary to add $V$ strictly convex in its argument?

Comment: It is true. No need for convexity. Just ask yourself what is the definition of a minimizer.

Comment: @user251257 What if $V(\cdot)$ has more than one argmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be surjective.
Then, $a$ is **a** minimizer of $V$ if and only if **any** $\alpha\in \phi^{-1}(a)$ is a minimizer of $W = V\circ \phi$:

1. Assume $a$ is a minimizer of $V$. Let $\alpha\in\phi^{-1}(a)$. Then, for every $\mu\in \mathbb R$ we have
   $$ W(\mu) = V(\underbrace{\phi(\mu)}_{\in \mathbb R}) \ge V(a) = V(\phi(\alpha)) = W(\alpha). $$
2. Assume $\alpha$ is a minimizer of $W$. Let $a = \phi(\alpha)$. Then, for every $u\in \mathbb R$ there exists a $\mu_u \in \phi^{-1}(u)$ and it follows
   $$ V(u) = V(\phi(\mu_u)) = W(\mu_u) \ge W(\alpha) = V(\phi(\alpha)) = V(a). $$

If you want to preserve the cardinality of the set of minimizers, then $\phi$ should be injective (at least on the set of minimizers). If $\phi$ isn't surjective, the set of minimizers might change. For example $V(u) = |u|$ has an unique minimizer, but $V(\exp(\mu))$ hasn't a minimizer, and $V(0\cdot\mu)$ is constant and has uncountably many minimizers.